# Connect a local database to another online

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect my local database (opened with PHPMyAdmin) with MySQL to another database online (amazon server). I need to update my local database with data on the other one.

Have you an idea of how I can do it? Trigger ??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need to copy all data from amazon server DB to your local once, or you want your local DB to be an updated redundant of the online one?

Comment: Hey, No i just need to update some data in amazon server DB . We have two DB in amazone server and in each DB i used two tables...in my local DB, i reproduced this two DB with tables that i'm using...i want to update this two tables